# How to link a field to a table and filter sub-table based on click in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I currently have an overview report of a participant inside a table. I want to be able to click on a patient ID in the report the "unhide a sub report" which shows the next level of information for the patient ID that I have clicked on. I am using SQl report builder 3.0 and I have tried a number of things including groups, functions etc and nothing seems to work. How do I go about this? I can give more detail if required below is a picture of what I currently have, I need the table below to be hidden until the top table patient ID is click and the sub table needs to filter by the ID.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can do this is to build another report, where you pass a parameter, and according to the parameter you do a selection. You add an action to one of the rows. The action should be to go to the next report where according to the passed parameter you do the selection. I will edit my answer soon and pass you a link where you can find more about this issue.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/MS-SQL_Reporting/A_8737-SSRS-can-be-also-used-for-user-inputs.html